# Symfony tree builder process array

Tags: php, symfony

I want to generate url in my application from config params.
I have folllowing config that I'm processing:

```
link:
        route_name: article
        route_params: {id: 1}
```

and my configuration:

```
->arrayNode('link')
    ->beforeNormalization()
        ->ifString()
        ->then(function ($v) { return [ 'direct' => $v]; })
    ->end()
    ->children()
        ->scalarNode('route_name')->end()
        ->arrayNode('route_params')->end()
        ->scalarNode('direct')->end()
    ->end()
->end()
```

I'm generating url by:

```
$this->router->generate($this->config['link']['route_name'],
            $this->config['link']['route_params']);
```

I don't know how to process array with **route_params**.
Amount and names of params will be different in each routes, so I can't just do:

```
->arrayNode('route_params')
    ->scalarNode('id')->end()
->end()
```

I'm getting this error now:

> Unrecognized option "id" under
>   "link.route_params"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
   ->arrayNode('route_params')
        ->useAttributeAsKey('name')
        ->prototype('scalar')->end()
    ->end()
```